# jQuery - Change paragraph when another input field is focused

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to web development and I got a problem using jQuery. I can't find anything on Google. Here's my problem:

I want to change a paragraph, it has to change if another input field is focused.

Here's a code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function() {
    if ($('#input1').focus()) {
     $('#paragraph').html("You picked input1!");
    }

    else if ($('#input1').focus()) {
     $('#paragraph').html("You picked input2!");
    }

    else {
     $('#paragraph').html("You picked a different input!");
    }
  }
});
```

The code works once, the paragraph says "You picked input1!" - but I want the event to be triggered every time I focus another input field. What's my mistake?

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: You should write your code in focus event.

Comment: in your else if you again used input1 only, change it to $('#input2').focus()

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I am a beginner @Mohammad

Comment: `$('#input1').focus(function(){/*focused*/})`

Answer (score 1):

You should be binding to the focus event for the inputs. Also, as one of the comments states, you are using `"#input1"` in both conditionals

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Assumption is that all #input{number} are input elements
    $("body").on("focus", "input", funcion() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#paragraph").text("You focused " + $this.attr("id"));
    });
});
```

The benefit of using `$("body").on("focus", "input", function() {})` is that if any new input tags are created within the body tag, the event will still affect them.

I also want to mention that calling [`$.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus) is *triggering* the focus event, not actually checking to see *if* the tag is focused. To do that, you should use `$.is(":focus")`, so in your code it would be `$("#input1").is(":focus")`

Comment: Works fine! Thank you!